# How can I back up the phone numbers on my iPhone?

Tags: data-synchronization, backup

I've just synchronized my iPhone and backed up contacts in both Outlook and GMail. However, it has saved the email addresses only. How can I back up the phone numbers on my phone?

Comment: Kelly - welcome to the site. Could you edit your question or answer here in the comments where specifically you want the phone numbers saved? Also - back up is confusing as for the contacts to go to gmail or outlook - that is usually seen as a sync and not simply a backup. Changes you make in outlook should sync to the phone and vice/versa. A backup is one way...

Answer (score 1):

If your whole contacts (Name, Cel, Email) are stored on Gmail, you can use it to sync over the air directly to your phone.

First, create a backup of your contacts and delete the ones you have in your iPhone (this will prevent any merging issues).

Go to **Preferences > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account**

Add your Gmail account and when prompted, turn on the "Contacts" option. This will import all your contacts from Gmail directly to your phone.

You're done! your Gmail contacts should be now in sync with your phone, if you use Outlook as your main application to edit your contacts, remember to sync it with Gmail first.

Comment: Please use caution - back up is not the same as a sync. If you delete your contacts and then restore - you might just as will end up with duplicates when google merges them down from the google servers. Have you made sure your sync is set up correctly with your PC/Mac through iTunes - the article here can help http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386 - once you have a good copy on your computer, it's easier to delete and trust the computer can get those contacts to google if needed.